# JSF 1.2 - generate dynamic ID attributes for tables using <h:dataTable>

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, datatable, jsf-1.2

What is the best way to create dynamic ID attributes for tables (in a loop) using `<h:dataTable>`?

We use the following:

- JSF 1.2
- JSP
- Sun Application Server 9.0_01
- JSTL 1.1

We have a page that has 8 tables.

Each table **MUST** have a unique ID attribute.

The tables are drawn by iterating over a Map that contains elements that contain table data.

The keys of the Map should be used when defining the tables' ID attributes.

Example:

If my map contains these keys:  `Dog, Cat, Mouse, Bird`

Ideally, I want the ID attributes of my tables to be: `dog-table, cat-table, mouse-table, bird-table`

Something random would work as well: `t1-table, t2-table, t3-table`

The ID attribute of `<h:dataTable>` does not permit EL expressions (so I can't access my map keys directly).

What is the best way to create my ID attributes?

Two approaches come to mind, but they both seem hacky:

1. use a scriptlet or JSP value expression
2. use jQuery to assign unique IDs to each table (after its rendered and before its processed)

The ultimate goal is to display these tables using jqGrid (so we're using jQuery anyways).

Any help would be awesome...

---

***NOTE:***

We are using a helper class to *simulate* iterating over a Map (since this can't be done in JSF 1.2).

In stead of actually iterating over a Map, we generate a List of objects that have a *name* and a `List<Foo>`.

The name represents the key and the List represents the rows of the table(s).

---

***Edit***:

It eventually occurred to me that `<h:dataTable>` generates its own unique IDs in this scenario.

The generated names are good enough to solve my issue...

Even though my page is working, I'm still curious about how to approach this situation in the future.

Comment: Is (Num of)datatable generates dynamically?,if yes then how you create that provide details for that.

Comment: Maybe it is possible for you to use the facelets `<ui:repeat>` tag instead of `<h:dataTable>`? This way you could define the ids for your HTML `<table>` tags in it manually.

Comment: @w4rumy - Boy do I wish we could switch to facelets... Unfortunately I'm working on a legacy system with hundreds of JSPs that can't really be changed like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you...

All expressions using the ${} syntax are evaluated immediately. These expressions can be used only within template text or as the value of a tag attribute that can accept runtime expressions.

```
   id="${data.map}-table
```